# vba how to auto insert sheet after scan barcode into textbox

Tags: excel, vba

currently my code is user scan barcode and press enter insert into sheet,but i would like to change it auto input after i scan barcode into textbox.

i had change  **Private Sub** type and according to research make some change but it don't work.

```
Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()
If ID.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Insert ID!", vbExclamation, "Warning!"

ElseIf ID.Value <> "" Then

Dim iRow1 As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")

iRow1 = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1 

With WS
 .Cells(iRow1, 1).Value = ID.Value
 End With
Unload Me
On Error Resume Next
UserForm1.Show
On Error GoTo 0

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful description of what happens when your code runs.  What does it do instead of working?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation:

You can implement the function Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Assuming your code bar reader "pokes" the character in a cell, it will be triggered.

You can also add sequence to the end of the basr code as in
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O72BKIGLpnQ